# Is it feasible to escape ' (single quote) with ESCAPE clause, if yes, then how to do it?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, oracle-12c, oracle-10g

I understand that we can use '' to escape a single quote in Oracle queries. However, I want to know if it is feasible to escape a single quote in the ESCAPE clause.

set up:

```
create table test_t ( x varchar2(100));
insert into test_t values ('it''s a string');
commit;
```

Dummy Query:

```
select * from test_t
 where x like '%''%' escape '''';
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think it should be escaped? Special characters that should be escaped when using `LIKE` operator are `%` and `_`.

```
SQL> select * from test_t where x like '%''%';

X
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
it's a string

SQL> select * from test_t where x like q'[%'%]';

X
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
it's a string
```

Comment: I understand that. I am wondering if it can be done. (ESCAPE with a single quote as argument)

Comment: @SameerPradhan `select * from test_t where x like '%''''%' escape '''';`

Comment: WOW.. How did you do that!! How 4 single quotes ended up searching string with a single quote. Please explain a bit.